# load jQuery charset

Tags: php, jquery

I hava 2 php files. `index.php` and `preview.php`

in the top of `index.php` I have this code

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

When I try to load content to `index.php` from `preview.php` using:

```
function preview_content(id)
{

    var thebutton = '#previewButton';
    $(thebutton).hide();
    $('#preview_area').load('preview.php?id='+id);
}
```

the content loaded with characters like this `M�laga CF`

I tried to put the same `utf-8` code in the top of `preview.php` but nothing changed. Is there any way to retrieve the content with `UTF-8` charset?

Comment: First, is the data hardcoded in the PHP script? If it is, check the file's charset. Make it UTF-8 also

Comment: All my files are written using `Coda2` for mac, and the default encoding is `UTF-8`

Comment: Try adding this in the beginning of the scripts: header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: I have tried to open the file directly from the web browser and everything works fine. So, I think the problem from jQuery.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check it for `.ajax()` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure about `preview.php`'s encoding is `UTF-8`. Your editor's default encoding applies newly created files but if you copied `preview.php` from somewhere else it's encoding might be different. Also adding `header('charset=utf-8');` as first line to `preview.php` might help. Like this;

```
<?php
header('charset=utf-8');
// your code below here
.
.
.
```

You can also use `.ajax()` and specify `contentType` instead of `.load()`;

```
function preview_content(id)
{

    var thebutton = '#previewButton';
    $(thebutton).hide();
    $.ajax({
        data: { "id" : id },
        type: "GET",
        url: "preview.php",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(output) {
            $('#preview_area').html(output);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried to open the file directly from the web browser and everything works fine. So, I think the problem from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The meta content attribute doesn't have a "Type=" part

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: I have tried to open the file directly from the web browser and everything works fine. So, I think the problem from jQuery.

Comment: which file? I am talking about index.php and not preview.php!

Answer (score 0):

The Emre Erkan's solution was right, but it needed "echo" before "header('...')"

Add this lines in the top of preview.php:

```
<?php
echo header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
?>
```

It worked in my website